# Need to get the instance variables and their default values with or without creating class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, instance-variables

I have a class from a library that I don't have any control over.

I want to get all the attributes and their default values of that class. Preferably without creating an instance if that is possible.

Example class -

```
class SeomClass():
  def __init()__(
    self,
    var1: builtins.str,
    var2: builtins.str,
    var3: typing.Optional[builtins.str] = None,
    var4: typing.Optional[builtins.str] = None,
  ) -> none
```

I need to get all the variables inside init and their default values.

Something like this

```
{"var1": null, "var2": null, "var3": None, "var4": None}
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: why don't u create a static method as a getter for all class variables?

Comment: This class the coming from a separate library which I can't edit or change.

Comment: Oh, if the original class does not have a static class variable or methods, then how are u expecting to get the class variables without instantiating it?

Comment: Ok let's say we can instantiate it, I need to dynamically instantiate it. I don't know what attributes to pass. There will be multiple classes. Is there a way to instantiate without passing any attributes and get all the variables as I asked in the question?

Comment: @JegathSuresh no there isn't. Note, objects do not have attributes unless you instantiate them normally. Also, your example above doesn't really make sense, are you assuming that all `__init__` arguments get assigned to equivalently named attributes? Are you actually asking about figuring out the signature of `__init__`?\

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes